# NHL Slapshot Roster Update

Tags: nhl-slapshot

I'm trying to get NHL Slapshot to update the roster and schedules but it's giving me the error "Cannot connect to EA server"... I don't know why because I've been playing online multiplayer for call of duty... any idea why the error happens and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather, the servers are shut down and things like roster updates cannot be done any longer unless you do it manually for all 30 teams..

Comment: Well that sucks, but seems like the case...